# str_replace with Last.fm urls

Tags: php, str-replace, last.fm

I'm writing a Last.FM script that shows what song you're listening to, and I'd like to be able to link the artist to the song title and everything.

How would I go about doing this? I mean, I'm assuming that I'll use `str_replace()`, but how?

The way Last.FM formats their urls is like this;

http://last.fm/artist/This+Is+A+Band

So basically what I'm asking is, how would I take my $artist variable, and convert those spaces to pluses, but only for the part of the script that prints the song information.

Here's my code:

```
$uname = "USERNAME";
$key = "API KEY";
$json = file_get_contents("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks=" . $uname . "&api_key=" . $key . "&format=json"); // Gets your data
if (strpos($json, 'nowplaying') !== false) {
list($currentsonginfo, $crap) = explode('{"nowplaying":"true"}}', $json);
list($crap, $v2) = explode('{"recenttracks":{"track":[{"artist":{"#text":"', $currentsonginfo);
list($artist, $restinfo) = explode('","', $v2);
list($crap, $currenttrack) = explode('"name":"', $restinfo); }
$playing = $artist . ' - ' . $currentrack; // Checks if a song is playing
if ($playing == ' - ') {
    echo '<a href="http://last.fm/user/' . $uname . '/">';
    echo "I'm not listening to anything."; // Only if you're not scrobbling
    echo "</a>";
} else {
    echo '<marquee>';
    echo '<a href="http://last.fm/user/' . $uname . '/">';
    echo "I'm currently listening to " . $currenttrack . " by " . $artist; // It shows when you're playing music!
    echo "</a>";
    echo '</marquee>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A url should never have spaces, so you can always convert all the spaces to +. Hence, you can just use str_replace(" ", "+", $artist).

Also, you can parse the json by using json_decode instead of exploding the string.

Comment: Oh, okay. Cool, thank you. Any chance you could tell me where in the world I should put the `str_replace()`? I've never used it before so I don't know how it works with URLs.

Comment: Replace $artist by str_replace(" ", "+", $artist):

echo "I'm currently listening to " . $currenttrack . " by " . str_replace(" ", "+", $artist); // It shows when you're playing music!

Comment: Your first parameter is search, and the second is replace, so this answer is backwards, it should be `str_replace("+"," ",$artist);`

Comment: Actually, Brian, you were wrong. It's how marrock said it was.

Comment: yeah... I thought you were switching the other way around (pluses into spaces. Sorry about that.

Comment: Oh, yeah, no problem @BrianVanderbusch.

Comment: Also, whoever downvoted @marrock's answer, what for? His answer was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

#### PHP `parse_url()`

php's [parse_url function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) will be very useful for this.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://last.fm/artist/This+Is+A+Band';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH); // will print an array of the different parts of the url you can access with flags
```

From there, it's just a matter of stripping the stuff you don't want by exploding the components of the path returned, getting the last item in your exploded array, and using `str_replace` with the params being in the order `search`, `replace`, `haystack`

```
<?php
$url = 'http://last.fm/artist/This+Is+A+Band';

$apiPath = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));

$parts = explode($apiPath, '/'); // get an array of the path components so you can access the artist

$artist = end($parts);  // moves array pointer to last structure

$artist = str_replace(' ','+',$artist); // turn your + into spaces
```